# Java - Generate New Filename for New BufferedImage Files

Tags: java, image-processing

Is it possible to generate a new image name for each image that is processed using the following code (I have highlighted the relevant section)?

```
public static void makeBinary(File image) { 
try{
    //Read in original image. 
    BufferedImage inputImg = ImageIO.read(image);

    //Obtain width and height of image.
    double image_width = inputImg.getWidth();
    double image_height = inputImg.getHeight();

    //New images to draw to.
    BufferedImage bimg = null;
    BufferedImage img = inputImg;

    //Draw the new image.      
    bimg = new BufferedImage((int)image_width, (int)image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D gg = bimg.createGraphics();
    gg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), null);


// ************* THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING DIFFICULTY ***************

    //Save new binary (output) image.   
    String temp = "_inverted";
    File fi = new File("images\\" + temp + ".jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bimg, "jpg", fi);

// ******************************************************************


}
 catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
 }
}
```

I have 300 images, numbered `001.jpg` - `300.jpg`, and what I would like is for each new outputted image to be named something along the lines of, `binary_001.jpg` - `binary_300.jpg`.

The method that calls `makeBinary()` is located in another class and is:

```
public static void listFiles() {

    File dir = new File("images");
    File imgList[] = dir.listFiles();

    if(dir.isDirectory()){
        for(File img : imgList){
            if(img.isFile()){
                MakeBinary.makeBinary(img);
                System.out.println(img + ": processed successfully.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Directory detected; skipping to next file,");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the filename from your `File image` parameter and add it to the new filename:

```
String temp = image.getName() + "_inverted";
File fi = new File("images\\" + temp + ".jpg");
ImageIO.write(bimg, "jpg", fi);
```

Comment: You probably want to strip the ending from `image.getName()` first though. Also for platform independence sake I wouldn't use `"images\\"` but `"images"+File.seperatorChar()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just concatenate name from the original image (in your code 'image' you pass to ImageIO with the string "_inverted", this way you would have original name for each image you process: image.jpg -> image_inverted.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
File fi = new File("images\\" + "binary_" + image.getName());
```

Should do the trick.

Or even better:

```
File fi = new File(image.getParent(), "binary_" + image.getName());
```